# How to check if there are columns in one table that are not in the other in R?

Tags: r

I have two datasets, one with 71 columns and one with 12 columns. Each dataset has columns, which are not columns in the other dataset. How can I automatically create a list of the columns, which are part of dataset 1, but are not part of dataset 2 and vice versa?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setdiff(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))
```

and

```
setdiff(colnames(df2), colnames(df1))
```